# JavaScript transform array of objects into another using lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    type: 'car',
    choices: [
      'audi',
      'honda',
      'bmw',
      'ford'
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'drink',
    choices: [
      'soda',
      'water',
      'tea',
      'coffee'
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'food',
    choices: [
      'chips',
      'pizza',
      'cookie',
      'pasta'
    ],
  }
]
```

Using lodash how to transform it into something that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    question: [
      {
        drink: "tea"
      },
      {
        car: "bmw"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: [
      {
        food: "cookie"
      },
      {
        car: "ford"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: [
      {
        drink: "soda"
      },
      {
        food: "pizza"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: [
      {
        food: "chips"
      },
      {
        drink: "water"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: [
      {
        car: "audi"
      },
      {
        food: "pasta"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: [
      {
        car: "honda"
      },
      {
        drink: "coffee"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

The logic is as follow:

- Every question has a combination of 2 choices where every choice is of different type example (car and food).
- Combination of different types should occur only twice (car, food).
- No duplication of choices.
- The selection of choices should be randomized.

I tried to Flatten the array using this function

```
    let flattenItems = _.flatMap(items, ({ type, choices}) =>
      _.map(choices, choice => ({
        question: [
          { type: type, choice: choice },
          { type: type, choice: choice }
        ],
      })
    ));
```

but it's not what I need, and it's not random. I not sure my approach is the correct one, I'm thinking I should use a filter or reduce

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated using JS or lodash would be good.

Comment: Yes, but the combination of each two different elements should only happen twice.

Comment: For example, the combination of (car and drink) should appear exactly twice in the whole result, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: OK, I got this the wrong way, I think. You are asking for something more complex than I initially thought. Each entry in the result would be `{ [obj1[randomObj].type] : obj1[randomObj].choices[randomChoice] }` and you are picking pairs of two types with an associated random answer. Sorry, for some reason I misread it initially as you only wanting combinations of pairs of random types. I got it now.

Comment: This is a good question. I want to ask one thing that how the main object will selected. You want them random or in sequence. I mean if there are 4 elements in array. Then you want to select from `1-2` then `2-3` then `3-4` then `4-1` then again `1-2` up to so on. In this case there will no combination from `2-4`. Do you want that or you want completely random..

Comment: It should be completely random. Not all combination should be there, just a combination that satisfy the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a combination from `types` and a random `choices` selecten with a check if a value is aleady used.

```js
function getCombinations(array, size) {

    function c(left, right) {

        function getQuestion({ type, choices }) {
            var random;
            do {
                random = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
            } while (taken.get(type).has(random))
            taken.get(type).add(random);
            return { [type]: random };
        }

        left.forEach((v, i, a) => {
            var temp = [...right, v];
            if (temp.length === size) {
                result.push({ question: temp.map(getQuestion) });
            } else {
                c([...a.slice(0, i), ...a.slice(i + 1)], temp);
            }
        });
    }

    var result = [],
        taken = new Map(array.map(({ type }) => [type, new Set]));

    c(array, []);
    return result;
}

var data = [
    { type: 'car', choices: ['audi', 'honda', 'bmw', 'ford'] },
    { type: 'drink', choices: ['soda', 'water', 'tea', 'coffee'] },
    { type: 'food', choices: ['chips', 'pizza', 'cookie', 'pasta'] }
];

console.log(getCombinations(data, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you. worked perfectly, I had to edit it a bit for better testing.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Lodash**

```js
function randomizedQues(items) {
  let result = [];
  let flattenItems = _.flatMap(items, ({ type, choices }) =>
    _.map(choices, choice => ({ type: type, choice: choice })
  ))

  while(flattenItems.length > 1) {
    let r1 = _.random(flattenItems.length - 1),
        e1 = flattenItems[r1];

    let r2 = _.random(flattenItems.length - 1),
        e2 = flattenItems[r2];      

    if(e1.type === e2.type) continue

    result.push({ question: [
        {[e1.type]: e1.choice},
        {[e2.type]: e2.choice}
      ] 
    })
    _.pullAt(flattenItems, [r1, r2])
  }
  return result
}

let items = [{"type":"car","choices":["audi","honda","bmw","ford"]},{"type":"drink","choices":["soda","water","tea","coffee"]},{"type":"food","choices":["chips","pizza","cookie","pasta"]}]

console.log(randomizedQues(items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly What I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This was my thinking, each different combination of types needs to appear twice. So I looped forwards over the array and combined each type with the proceeding types.
Then I looped backwards over the array and combined each type with the preceeding types. At the same time I used `Math.random()` to pick a random choice from the `choices` subarray. The only problem is that this does not enforce strict duplicate elimination but relies on RNG to guarantee a low chance of duplicates. You should be able to add duplicate checking code inside each loop just before you create the new question.

```js
function buildQuestions(data) {
  const questions = []
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++)
      questions.push({question: [{[data[i].type]: data[i].choices[Math.round(Math.random() * (data[i].choices.length - 1))]},
          {[data[j].type]: data[j].choices[Math.round(Math.random() * (data[j].choices.length - 1))]}]})

  for (let i = data.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
      questions.push({question: [{[data[i].type]: data[i].choices[Math.round(Math.random() * (data[i].choices.length - 1))]},
          {[data[j].type]: data[j].choices[Math.round(Math.random() * (data[j].choices.length - 1))]}]})

  return questions
}

const choices = [{ type: 'car',choices: ['audi','honda','bmw','ford'],},{type: 'drink', choices: ['soda','water','tea','coffee'],},{type: 'food',choices: ['chips','pizza','cookie','pasta'],}]

console.log(buildQuestions(choices))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to keep removing items from each array until you're left without enough options remaining to fill in any more questions.

To help do this, we have functions which take in an array, and return a random item, plus the array without that item. We can then build the questions with that data, ensuring that each item is only used once.

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), x)

const data = [
    { type: 'car', choices: ['audi', 'honda', 'bmw', 'ford'] },
    { type: 'drink', choices: ['soda', 'water', 'tea', 'coffee'] },
    { type: 'food', choices: ['chips', 'pizza', 'cookie', 'pasta'] }
];

const getArrayIndexPair = array => [
  array,
  getRandom(array),
];

const subtractItemFromArray = ([array, index]) => [
  array.slice(index, index + 1)[0],
  [
    ...array.slice(0, index),
    ...array.slice(index + 1, array.length)
  ]
];

const getRandom = array => Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
const takeRandom = pipe(
  getArrayIndexPair,
  subtractItemFromArray,
);

const choicesKeyedByType = data
  .reduce((p, c) => ({
    ...p,
    [c.type]: c.choices,
  }), {})

const formQuestions = (choices, questions=[]) => {
  if (Object.keys(choices).length <= 1) {
    return questions;
  }

  const [keyOne, remainingKeys] = takeRandom(Object.keys(choices));
  const [keyTwo] = takeRandom(remainingKeys);
  
  const [choiceOne, remainingKeyOneChoices] = takeRandom(choices[keyOne]);
  const [choiceTwo, remainingKeyTwoChoices] = takeRandom(choices[keyTwo]);

  const newChoices = {
    ...choices,
    [keyOne]: remainingKeyOneChoices,
    [keyTwo]: remainingKeyTwoChoices,
  };
  
  const newChoicesWithoutEmpty = Object.keys(newChoices)
    .filter(key => newChoices[key].length > 0)
    .reduce((p, c) => ({
      ...p,
      [c]: newChoices[c]
    }), {});
    
  const newQuestions = [
    ...questions,
    {
      [keyOne]: choiceOne,
      [keyTwo]: choiceTwo,
    }
  ];
  
  return formQuestions(
    newChoicesWithoutEmpty,
    newQuestions,
  );
};

console.dir(formQuestions(choicesKeyedByType))
```